# Git, XPages and branch woes

Tags: git, xpages

I am trying to use Git with Domino Designer (DD) but have hit problem. I setup GitLab for use with DD - I can export the project in DD and make changes which are sync'ed back and forth no problem. I now would like to create a branch (which I do in Git - lets call it Version_2_0), switch to that branch and make my Version 2.0 changes. This works without a hitch. If I now need to make changes to the main code stream (i.e. the master - bug fixes or what not) I commit my current branch (i.e. Version_2_0). Change to the master branch and everything looks good in DD. I then fix whatever problem I have and commit it. I do the rollout of my update and my users have their updates. I then switch back to my branch (i.e. Version_2_0) and find that my changes are no longer being reflected in DD - they are still on disk but not in DD.

Sorry for the funny explanation but maybe this example will help:

In this example I am missing the form 8. Atilla in the Notes Client - I have the same problems whether it is a Notes Classic form or Notes Modern i.e. XPages

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experiences the automatic import and export from the On Disk Project (ODP) isn't triggered immediately after switching branches. It might run after few minutes or so, but that's annoying when you're waiting for it. The setting `Refresh automatically` (Preferences > General > Workspace) might also be affecting this by the way.

To get the NSF up to date after a branch switch, what I used to do was to refresh the On Disk Project in Designer first: from the Package Explorer > right click on the project and click 'Refresh'. That will update the project in DDE. After that I manually synced with the NSF (right click > Team Development > Sync with On-Disk project).

What I would recommend now however is to use [Swiper](https://github.com/camac/Swiper/). That is absolutely a must-have plugin if you're doing source control with Designer. In the latest version (requires Designer client 901 FP8) it comes with a new Designer menu that includes a button (the 'Magic 8-ball') to perform the steps I used to do manually: refresh the ODP and sync with the NSF.

Even if you're not on FP8 yet I would still recommend installing it.

Comment: I do have Swiper installed (am on the beta as I have FP8 installed) but it was behaving weirdly (menu greyed out, not doing anything etc.) ... anyway, since my DD install is about 5 years old I have wiped it clean and am currently doing a new install - I'll report back here as soon as thats finished to see if it changed anything :o)

Comment: Thank you Mark - doing a Refresh in the Package Explorer fixed it for me. I seem to be missing the menu options from Swiper (the 'Magic 8-ball') but I'm sure that I'm just doing something wrong :o)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an source control export and I guess that your have tried to manually sync the project.
So I would suggest that you have an empty on disk project that you switch to and sync with to "clean the database" before switching back after a branch switch.

perhaps someone has some better solution

Comment: Fredrick, when you say "manually sync the project" what do you mean? I am doing a "Sync with On-Disk Project..." from the "Team Development" menu in Designer just to be 100% sure that the files are being picked up. I have the top 3 settings selected in "File >Preferences >Domino Designer >Source Control" i.e. that the files should be updated automatically. Am I missing something?